# how to find documentation for Postgres Linux packages?

Tags: linux, postgresql

There are PostgreSQL binaries in yum package except for server and client.

```
postgresql96-contrib.x86_64
postgresql96-debuginfo.x86_64
postgresql96-devel.x86_64
postgresql96-docs.x86_64
postgresql96-odbc.x86_64
postgresql96-plperl.x86_64
postgresql96-plpython.x86_64
postgresql96-pltcl.x86_64
postgresql96-tcl.x86_64
postgresql96-tcl-debuginfo.x86_64
postgresql96-test.x86_64
```

I can assume the purpose of binaries, but I want to check it in documents.
How can I find the documents for them?

Comment: The [help/on-topic] pretty clearly says *Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow*. Finding documentation for PostgreSQL binaries would be an *off-site resource*.

Comment: I thought how to use command for document like `man` or some command in `yum` is not off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dnf info postgresql96-contrib
```

or (old RHEL/CentOS)

```
yum info postgresql96-contrib
```

If you have downloaded the RPMs:

```
rpm -qif
```

Comment: `show` option was not found in `yum`, but there is `yum info`. Thanks!